# Maven install - SQL problem / suitable driver

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two Maven Project with exactly same code.
I'm running project number one just from `public static void main` method and it connects to database and works perfectly, but when I use `maven install` and try to run it as a plugin in BukkitMC server it tells me all the time
`"no suitable jdbc driver found"`

I have dependencies at `pom.xml` in both project the same, so I'm pretty sure it works.

It's just all about this `MAVEN INSTALL`. 
Have you got an idea?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
App app = new App();
app.insertData("INSERT INTO users (login,password,email) VALUES ('a','b','c');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `install` goal do also `package` goal.

 In `package` your project is archived (eg:jar) and after on `install` is deploy.
 
Could check what is inside archive(`jar`) and if not any `sql-driver` then you could search for the appropriate way to be packages from maven also with driver.

 Other option is to add driver maybe manually on your server.